Is it possible to do Lazy Loading on Combobox component?
I have Parent, Child & Grand Child Component.
Parent Component Display Lazy Loading on LWC data table which I already implemented which loads first 100 records and using onLoadMore event it performs Lazy Loading Properly.
Now I have Child Component which I am displaying under Parent Component which calls Grand Child Component where I show  Multiselect Picklist value for all 4 Field filters which I have implemented.
Challenges: When I test this on 10000 records then the Component takes significant time to load. One of the main reason I observed, I pass All 10000 records to Child so that based on those Data Filter value should display. But Under Child I am thinking if I can somehow apply lazy loading so that It shows first 100 records and if I scroll then it loads next 100 records similar to LWC data table.
Below is my Parent LWC HTML Code where I am calling Child LWC:
<template>
    <lightning-card title={DashboardName}>
        <template if:true={invoiceData}>
            <c-dynamic-filter filters={filters} tdata={invoiceData} onfilter={handleFilter} onresetfilter={handleResetFilter}></c-dynamic-filter>
            </br>
            <template if:true={tableColumns}>
                <div class="slds-var-p-around_small" style="height: 2000px;">
                    <lightning-datatable
                    class="slds-table_header-fixed_container slds-scrollable_x slds-border_top slds-table_striped slds-max-medium-table_stacked-horizontal"
                    key-field="Id" data={paginationInvoiceData} columns={tableColumns} sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                    sorted-by={sortedBy} onsort={doSorting} onrowaction={handleRowAction} load-more-offset="100"
                    enable-infinite-loading onloadmore={handleLoadMore}  hide-checkbox-column show-row-number-column
                    >
                </lightning-datatable>
                </div>
                
            </template>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

Below Is Child LWC HTML & JS Code which calls Grand Child Component:
HTML :
<template>
    <template lwc:if={filters}>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-var-p-left_small lgc-bg">
            <template for:each={filters} for:item="filter">
                <div class="slds-col" key={filter.api}>
                    <template lwc:if={filter.stdIp}>
                        <lightning-input name={filter.api} type={filter.type} label={filter.label} value={filter.value}
                            onchange={handleChange}>
                        </lightning-input>
                    </template>
                    <template lwc:if={filter.picklist}>
                        <c-multi-select-combobox onselect={handleSelect} label={filter.label} options={filter.options}
                            selected-values={selectedValues} field-name={filter.api}></c-multi-select-combobox>
                    </template>
                    <template lwc:if={filter.multipicklist}>
                        <c-multi-select-combobox onselect={handleSelect} label={filter.label} options={filter.options}
                            selected-values={selectedValues} multi-select={filter.multiselect} field-name={filter.api}>
                        </c-multi-select-combobox>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </template>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <br>
                <lightning-button-icon class="buttonposition" icon-name="action:reset_password" variant="brand"
                    onclick={resetFilters}></lightning-button-icon>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>

JS:
import {
    LightningElement,
    api
} from 'lwc';
import selectOption from '@salesforce/label/c.PicklistSelectOption';
export default class DynamicFilter extends LightningElement {
    @api filters;
    @api tdata;
    originalTdata;
    @api selectedValues = [];
    label={
        selectOption
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        this.showData(this.tdata);
    }
    showData(tableData) {
        let date;
        this.originalTdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tableData));
        this.filters = typeof this.filters === 'string' ? JSON.parse(this.filters) : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.filters));
        this.filters.forEach(item => {
            item[item.type] = true;
            if (item.type == 'text' || item.type == 'number' || item.type == 'tel' || item.type == 'date' || item.type == 'datetime' || item.type == 'color') {
                item.stdIp = true;
            }
            if (item.type == 'picklist') {
                item.options = [];
            }
            if (item.type == 'multipicklist') {
                item.options = [];
            }
        });

        this.originalTdata.forEach(item => {
            this.filters.forEach(filter => {
                if (filter.type === 'picklist' || filter.type === 'multipicklist') {
                    const value = item[filter.api];
                    if (filter.api === 'Order Date') {
                        if (value.includes('/')) {
                            const [day, month, year] = value.split('/').map(Number);
                            date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
                        } else if (value.includes('-')) {
                            const [year, month, day] = value.split('-').map(Number);
                            date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
                        }


                        if (!isNaN(date.getTime()) && !filter.options.includes(date.getFullYear())) {
                            filter.options.push(date.getFullYear());
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!filter.options.includes(value) && value != null) {
                            filter.options.push(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        this.filters.forEach(filter => {
            if (filter.type === 'picklist' || filter.type === 'multipicklist') {
                filter.options.sort();
                filter.options = [{
                    label: this.label.selectOption,
                    value: 'All'
                }].concat(filter.options.map(item => ({
                    label: String(item),
                    value: String(item)
                })));
            }
        });
    }
        
    handleChange(event) {
        if (event.target.name === 'Order Date') {
            this.filters.find(filter => filter.api === event.target.name).value = event.target.value;
        } else {
            this.filters.find(filter => filter.api === event.target.name).value = event.target.value;
        }

        this.filterData();
    }

    sendData(data) {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('filter', {
            detail: {
                data
            }
        }));
    }

    handleSelect(event) {
        if (event.detail.payloadType === 'multi-select' || event.detail.payloadType === 'picklist') {
            this.selectedValues = event.detail.payloadType === 'multi-select' ? event.detail.payload.values : event.detail.payload.value;
            const filter = this.filters.find(filter => filter.api === event.detail.fieldName);
            if (filter) {
                filter.value = this.selectedValues.length > 0 ? this.selectedValues : null;
            }

            this.filterData();
        }
    }

    filterData() {
        let itemDate;
        let data = this.originalTdata.filter(item => {
            return this.filters.every(filter => {
                if (!filter.value || (Array.isArray(filter.value) && filter.value.length === 0)) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (filter.type === 'text' || filter.type === 'number' || filter.type === 'tel') {
                    return String(item[filter.api]).toLowerCase().includes(String(filter.value).toLowerCase());
                }

                if (filter.type === 'picklist' || filter.type === 'multipicklist') {
                    if (filter.api === 'Order Date') {
                        if(item[filter.api].includes('/')){
                            const [day, month, year] = item[filter.api].split('/');
                            itemDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
                        }
                        else if(item[filter.api].includes('-')){
                        const [year, month, day] = item[filter.api].split('-');
                        itemDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
                        }
                        if (Array.isArray(filter.value)) {
                            return filter.value.some(val => String(itemDate.getFullYear()).includes(val));
                        } else {
                            return String(itemDate.getFullYear()).includes(String(filter.value));
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (Array.isArray(filter.value)) {
                            return filter.value.some(val => String(item[filter.api]).toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase()));
                        } else {
                            return String(item[filter.api]).toLowerCase().includes(String(filter.value).toLowerCase());
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (filter.type === 'date' || filter.type === 'datetime') {
                    const itemDate = new Date(item[filter.api]);
                    const filterDate = new Date(filter.value);
                    return !isNaN(itemDate.getTime()) && itemDate.toISOString().split('T')[0] === filterDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
                }
            });
        });
        this.sendData(data);
    }



    resetFilters() {
        this.filters.forEach(filter => {
            if (filter.type === 'text' || filter.type === 'number' || filter.type === 'tel' || filter.type === 'date' || filter.type === 'datetime' || filter.type === 'color') {
                filter.value = '';
            }
            if (filter.type === 'picklist' || filter.type === 'multipicklist') {
                filter.value = null;
            }
        });

        // Reset standard inputs
        let textInputs = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');
        textInputs.forEach(input => {
            input.value = '';
        });

        // Reset multi-select comboboxes
        let multiSelectComboboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('c-multi-select-combobox');
        multiSelectComboboxes.forEach(combobox => {
            combobox.reset();
        });

        // Reset filters array to ensure all changes are applied
        this.filters = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.filters));
        this.sendData(this.originalTdata);
        this.resetData();
    }
    resetData() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('resetfilter', {
            detail: {
                value : true
            }
        }));
    }
}

Grand Child HTML & JS:
HTML :
<template>

    <!-- Header Label -->
    <template if:true={label}>
        <label class="slds-form-element__label">{label}</label>
    </template>
    <div class="slds-combobox_container">
        <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open" aria-expanded="true"
            aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
            <!-- Search Input -->
            <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
                <lightning-input disabled={disabled} class="inputBox" placeholder={labels.selectedAnOption} onblur={blurEvent}
                    onclick={showOptions} onkeyup={filterOptions} value={searchString} auto-complete="off"
                    variant="label-hidden" id="combobox-id-1"></lightning-input>
                <lightning-icon class="slds-input__icon" icon-name="utility:down" size="x-small"
                    alternative-text="search"></lightning-icon>
            </div>
            <!-- Dropdown List -->
            <template if:true={showDropdown}>
                <div id="listbox-id-1" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-5 slds-dropdown_fluid" data-field={fieldName}  onscroll={handleScroll}>
                    <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical recordListBox" role="presentation">
                        <template if:false={message}>
                            <template for:each={optionData} for:item="option">
                                <template if:true={option.isVisible}>
                                    <li key={option.value} data-id={option.value} onmousedown={selectItem}
                                        class="slds-listbox__item eachItem">
                                        <template if:true={option.selected}>
                                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:check" size="x-small"
                                                alternative-text="icon"></lightning-icon>
                                        </template>
                                        <span
                                            class="slds-media slds-listbox__option_entity verticalAlign slds-truncate">{option.label}</span>
                                    </li>
                                </template>
                            </template>
                        </template>
                        <template if:true={message}>
                            <li class="slds-listbox__item">
                                <span
                                    class="slds-media slds-listbox__option_entity verticalAlign slds-truncate">{message}</span>
                            </li>
                        </template>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

JS:
import {
    LightningElement,
    track,
    api
} from 'lwc';
import selectedOption from '@salesforce/label/c.PicklistSelectedOption';
import selectedAnOption from '@salesforce/label/c.PicklistSelectAnOption';
export default class MultiSelectCombobox extends LightningElement {
    @api options;
    @api selectedValue;
    @api selectedValues = [];
    @api label;
    @api minChar = 2;
    @api disabled = false;
    @api multiSelect = false;
    @track value;
    @track values = [];
    @track optionData;
    @track searchString;
    @track message;
    @track showDropdown = false;
    @api fieldName;
    labels={
        selectedOption,
        selectedAnOption
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        this.showDropdown = false;
        let optionData = this.options ? (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.options))) : null;
        let value = this.selectedValue ? (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.selectedValue))) : null;
        let values = this.selectedValues ? (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.selectedValues))) : null;

        if (value || values) {
            var searchString;
            var count = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < optionData.length; i++) {
                if (this.multiSelect) {
                    if (values.includes(optionData[i].value)) {
                        optionData[i].selected = true;
                        console.log('Option Data val:'+optionData[i].value);
                        count++;
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('Else Option Data val:'+optionData[i].value);
                    if (optionData[i].value == value) {
                        searchString = optionData[i].label;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (this.multiSelect)
                this.searchString = count + ' ' +this.labels.selectedOption;
            else
                this.searchString = searchString;
        } else {
            this.searchString = '';
        }

        this.value = value;
        this.values = values;
        this.optionData = optionData;
    }

    filterOptions(event) {
        console.log('filterOptions:'+event.target.value);
        this.searchString = event.target.value;
        if (this.searchString && this.searchString.length > 0) {
            this.message = '';
            if (this.searchString.length >= this.minChar) {
                var flag = true;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.optionData.length; i++) {
                    if (this.optionData[i].label.toLowerCase().trim().includes(this.searchString.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                        this.optionData[i].isVisible = true;
                        flag = false;
                    } else {
                        this.optionData[i].isVisible = false;
                    }
                }
                if (flag) {
                    this.message = "No results found for '" + this.searchString + "'";
                }
            }
            this.showDropdown = true;
        } else {
            this.showDropdown = false;
        }
    }

    selectItem(event) {
        const selectedVal = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        console.log('selectedVal:' + JSON.stringify(selectedVal));
        let allSelected = selectedVal === 'All';
    
        // Handle the "All" selection
        if (allSelected) {
            let allOptions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.optionData));
            const allAlreadySelected = allOptions.every(option => option.selected);
    
            if (allAlreadySelected) {
                // If "All" is unchecked, unselect all values
                console.log('Unselecting all options...');
                allOptions.forEach(option => {
                    option.selected = false;
                    const index = this.values.indexOf(option.value);
                    if (index > -1) {
                        this.values.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // Select all options
                allOptions.forEach(option => {
                    if (!option.selected) {
                        option.selected = true;
                        this.values.push(option.value);
                    }
                });
            }
    
            this.searchString = allOptions.length + ' ' + this.labels.selectedOption;
            this.optionData = allOptions;
    
            if (this.multiSelect) {
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                this.showDropdown = false;
            }
        } 
        // Handle individual item selection
        else if (selectedVal) {
            let options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.optionData));
            const option = options.find(opt => opt.value === selectedVal);
    
            if (this.multiSelect) {
                if (this.values.includes(option.value)) {
                    this.values.splice(this.values.indexOf(option.value), 1);
                } else {
                    this.values.push(option.value);
                }
                option.selected = !option.selected;
    
                // Check if any options are unchecked, then uncheck "All"
                const anyUnchecked = options.some(opt => opt.value !== 'All' && !opt.selected);
                const allOption = options.find(opt => opt.value === 'All');
                if (allOption) {
                    allOption.selected = !anyUnchecked; // If any option is unchecked, uncheck "All"
                    if (!anyUnchecked) {
                        if (!this.values.includes('All')) {
                            this.values.push('All');
                        }
                    } else {
                        const index = this.values.indexOf('All');
                        if (index > -1) {
                            this.values.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                this.value = option.value;
                this.searchString = option.label;
            }
    
            // Update the options and search string
            this.optionData = options;
            if (this.multiSelect) {
                const count = this.values.length;
                this.searchString = count + ' ' + this.labels.selectedOption;
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                this.showDropdown = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    

    showOptions() {
        if (this.disabled == false && this.options) {
            this.message = '';
            this.searchString = '';
            var options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.optionData));
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                options[i].isVisible = true;
            }
            if (options.length > 0) {
                this.showDropdown = true;
            }
            this.optionData = options;
        }
    }

    removePill(event) {
        var value = event.currentTarget.name;
        var count = 0;
        var options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.optionData));
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            if (options[i].value === value) {
                options[i].selected = false;
                this.values.splice(this.values.indexOf(options[i].value), 1);
            }
            if (options[i].selected) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        this.optionData = options;
        if (this.multiSelect)
            this.searchString = count + ' ' +this.labels.selectedOption;
    }

    blurEvent() {
        console.log('blurEvent...');
        let previousLabel;
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.optionData.length; i++) {
            if (this.optionData[i].value === this.value) {
                previousLabel = this.optionData[i].label;
            }
            if (this.optionData[i].selected) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (this.multiSelect)
            this.searchString = count + ' ' +this.labels.selectedOption;
        else
            this.searchString = previousLabel;

        this.showDropdown = false;
        if (this.multiSelect) {
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('select', {
                detail: {
                    'fieldName': this.fieldName,
                    'payloadType': 'multi-select',
                    'payload': {
                        'values': this.values
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
        if (!this.multiSelect) {
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('select', {
                detail: {
                    'fieldName': this.fieldName,
                    'payloadType': 'picklist',
                    'payload': {
                        'value': this.value
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
    }
    @api reset() {
        this.values = [];
        this.searchString = '';
        this.optionData.forEach(option => {
            option.selected = false;
            option.isVisible = true;
        });
        this.showDropdown = false;
        this.optionData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.optionData)); // Ensure reactive update
    }
    
    
    handleScroll(){
        //Is it possible to do lazy loading?
    }

}

Can someone please help me here? How Can I add Lazy loading to Combobox component?

I haven’t done lazy loading as such, but then general approach I’ve used is to only display a small number of records (eg 50) and have a search at the top. Having said that, I’ve only tested this approach with a few thousand records and the performance seems acceptable.

Records that you mentioned, was this a part of Mutliselect combo box or Datatable? I am looking for lazy loading in Multiselect combo box option.
